# Cannot /Post - Login Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, authentication, ejs

I am creating an app and I need a SignIn / SignUp functionality for the same. Here is my SignIn HTML:

```
 <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >
      <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

       <form action="verifySignin" method="post" id="verifySignin" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
       <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
       <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username" required="" autofocus="" >                                        
    </div>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
 <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
</div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
   <!-- Button -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
      <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button> 
   </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12 control">
      <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" > Don't have an account? 
 <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
 Sign Up Here
</a>
 </div>
</div>
 </div>    
</form>     
 </div>
```

My app.js has the following to route:

```
app.post('/verifySignin', home.verifySignin);
app.get('/verifySignin', home.verifySignin);
```

Under routes folder> I have created a home.js file which contains the following:

```
function verifySignin(req,res)
 {

  req.session.name=req.param("username");
  var password = req.param("password");
  console.log("session name:"+req.session.name);
  var verifyUserQuery="select username, password from Users where Username='"+req.param("username")+"' and Password = '"+req.param("password")+"'";
  mysql.fetchData(function(err,results){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    else 
    {
        if(results.username==req.param("username") && results.password == password){
            res.render('kanban', { name: req.param("username") });}
        else {
            res.render('ErrorPage');
        }
    }  
},verifyUserQuery);
 }
  exports.verifySignin=verifySignin;
```

When I click on the Login button, I get the error : Cannot POST /verifySignin. 
Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it like,

```
var users = require('./home/users');
```

in addition, this is a very bad practice due to security concerns

```
"select username, password from Users where Username='"+req.param("username")+"' and Password = '"+req.param("password")+"'"
```

pass values as parameters or bind them.

Comment: Yeah, I will change the SQL query part. Not sure I understood this part: var users = require('./home/users'); Where should I use it??